# JetBrains RubyMine 3.2.4 debugger not working

Tags: ruby, debugging, rubygems, rubymine

Running with Ruby 1.9.2

The IDE complains that The gem ruby-debug-base19x is required and offers to install it.

However, upon attempting to install it it displays the message

> Failed to install gems. Following gems were not installed: C:/Program
>   Files (x86)/JetBrains/RubyMine
>   3.2.4/rb/gems/ruby-debug-base19x-0.11.30.pre2.gem: Error installing ruby-debug-base19x-0.11.30.pre2.gem: The 'linecache19' native gem
>   requires installed build tools. Please update your PATH to include
>   build tools or download the DevKit from
>   'http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads' and follow the instructions at
>   'http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit'
>   C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/RubyMine
>   3.2.4/rb/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.17.beta8.gem: Error installing ruby-debug-ide-0.4.17.beta8.gem: The 'ruby-debug-ide' native gem
>   requires installed build tools. Please update your PATH to include
>   build tools or download the DevKit from
>   'http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads' and follow the instructions at
>   'http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit'
>   linecache19 (0.5.12): Error installing linecache19: The 'linecache19'
>   native gem requires installed build tools. Please update your PATH to
>   include build tools or download the DevKit from
>   'http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads' and follow the instructions at
>   'http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit'

I followed its advice to download the DevKit - but the DevKit upon attempting to install, said that it was already correctly installed as part of Ruby.

Any advice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is not specific to RubyMine, I'd try to reinstall Ruby and DevKit from scratch.
Verify that DevKit actually works using a test from the [installation guide](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit):

```
gem install rdiscount --platform=ruby
ruby -rubygems -e "require 'rdiscount'; puts RDiscount.new('**Hello RubyInstaller**').to_html"
```

If it works fine, try to install the debug gems manually from the console using the following commands:

```
gem install ruby-debug-base19x --pre
gem install ruby-debug-ide --pre
```

Post logs, provide more details if it still doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

The gem that rubymine debugger installs by itself conflicts with the existing debug gem in the gemset. Uninstall the existing debug gems, you can get a list by running `gem list | grep debug` and let rubymine install its own version. Also make sure that you do not have a debug gem mentioned in the Gemfile and also there should not be any debug gem in the global gemset.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

i was able to get it working by uninstalling and reinstalling RubyMine. Then everything worked perfectly, as expected.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There is an [open issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RUBY-9418?query=p) on this at the RubyMine forum. The answer by Roman Melnik worked for me (but my environment is Mac OS).